# How to display no. of buttons based on media screen size in Angular.js?

Tags: angularjs

Initially above the media screen size of **1207** I will be displaying 6 (n) buttons out of 20 in between two arrows (left arrow and right arrow). Initially left arrow will be inactive. When user clicks on right arrow left arrow should get active and will navigate to next buttons (n+1) (after reaching end right arrow will become inactive).

When media screen size gets reduced than I need to show limited buttons between two arrows.

I have hardcoded the number of buttons to visible as 6 => `$scope._lastRoleIndex    = 5;`, this will display 6 buttons.

But I need to display buttons dynamically within the two arrows (left arrow and right arrow).

**My controller :**

```
$scope._firstRoleIndex = 0;
$scope._lastRoleIndex = 5;
$scope.isLeftRoleActive = false;
$scope.isRightRoleActive = true;
$scope.filteredRoles = [];

/** Show Prev Image **/
$scope.showPrev = function () {

    if ($scope._firstRoleIndex > 0) --$scope._lastRoleIndex;
    $scope._firstRoleIndex = ($scope._firstRoleIndex > 0) ? --$scope._firstRoleIndex : 0;

    if ($scope._firstRoleIndex == 0) {
        $scope.isLeftRoleActive = false;
        $scope.isRightRoleActive = true;
    }

    $scope.showFilteredRoles();

};

/** Show Next Image **/
$scope.showNext = function () {
    debugger;
    if ($scope._lastRoleIndex < $scope.roles.length - 1) ++$scope._firstRoleIndex;
    $scope._lastRoleIndex = ($scope._lastRoleIndex < $scope.displayrole.length - 1) ? ++$scope._lastRoleIndex : $scope.displayrole.length - 1;

    if ($scope._lastRoleIndex == $scope.displayrole.length - 1) {
        $scope.isLeftRoleActive = true;
        $scope.isRightRoleActive = false;
    }

    $scope.showFilteredRoles();
};

/** Show Filtered Image **/
$scope.showFilteredRoles = function () {
    debugger;
    console.log($scope._lastRoleIndex);

    $scope.filteredRoles = [];

    if ($scope.displayrole.length >= 5) {
        for (var i = $scope._firstRoleIndex; i <= $scope._lastRoleIndex; i++) {
            $scope.filteredRoles.push($scope.displayrole[i]);
        }
    } else {
        for (var i = $scope._firstRoleIndex; i <= $scope.displayrole.length - 1; i++) {
            $scope.filteredRoles.push($scope.displayrole[i]);
        }
    }


};
```

**My HTML**

```
<section class="showPrevious">
    <img src="css/images/left-nav_active.png" alt="" class="arrow" ng-click="showPrev()" ng-show="isLeftRoleActive" style="cursor: pointer;" />
    <img src="css/images/left-nav_inactive.png" alt="" class="arrow" ng-hide="isLeftRoleActive || displayrole.length<=6" style="cursor: not-allowed;" />
</section>

<section class="mytopmenu">
    <ul class="myul" role="tablist">

        <li class="myli" ng-repeat="role in filteredRoles track by $index" ng-class="{active:isSelected($index)}"><a href ng-click="displaySelectedRole(role, $index)">{{role}}</a></li>


    </ul>
</section>
<section class="showNext"><img src="css/images/right-nav_active.png" alt="" class="arrow" ng-click="showNext()" ng-show="isRightRoleActive" style="cursor: pointer;" ng-hide="displayrole.length<=6" />
    <img src="css/images/right-nav_inactive.png" alt="" class="arrow" ng-hide="isRightRoleActive || displayrole.length<=6" style="cursor: not-allowed;" />
</section>
```

[image: navigation]

Comment: what exactly are you asking ?
how many buttons would fit in your screen ?

Comment: Yes. Initially before media screen size of 1207, I am displaying 6 buttons as in above image. If i click on right navigation button it move one button before.  But if my media screen size is less than 1206 then I would like to display only 6 buttons.

Comment: Based on `$scope._lastRoleIndex    = 5;` in controller. How can i display using media screen size

Answer (score 0):

In your case you want to show buttons according to your window size. It shows you don't want to reduce the size of you buttons. 
By default you are showing 6 buttons on 1207 window size, it means one button for 200 (arround). By default on 1207 window $scope._lastRoleIndex is 5 it means **$scope._lastRoleIndex = 1207/240** (arround). So what you can do is get the number of buttons according to window width with below code,

```
  $scope._firstRoleIndex   = 0;
  $scope._lastRoleIndex = Math.round(window.innerWidth/240)
  if($scope._lastRoleIndex < 1){ $scope._lastRoleIndex = 1 }

   $(document).ready(function(){
      $(window).resize(function(){
       $scope._lastRoleIndex = Math.round(window.innerWidth/240)
       if($scope._lastRoleIndex < 1){ $scope._lastRoleIndex = 1 }
       $scope.showFilteredRoles();
       $scope.$$phase || $scope.$apply();
      });
  });

  $scope.isLeftRoleActive     = false;
  $scope.isRightRoleActive    = true;
  $scope.filteredRoles  = [];
```

May be it helps you. Best of luck :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But it taking static value as the controller gets intialized first time only. How can i call the controller to change the $scope._lastRoleIndex value on each media screen

Comment: Did you put all my code there ? if you'll put my code it will not show 6 buttons on mobile screen, Because i did not set the $scope._lastRoleIndex value to 5

Comment: Yes. But when page is loading it will call the controller only at on-loading. If I decrease the screen size and refresh the page the above code is working fine as onloading the media screen size is changed. But for every screen reduction user won't refresh the page. So i need

Comment: So is there any option to call a function inside media screen i.e., @media screen and (min-width: xxxpx) {   }

Comment: Ok, got it so you want to make it dynamic on windo resize ?

Comment: Edited answer for you, please try once.

Comment: code is correct. it working fine but i works when i reduce the screen size and refresh the page. Because controller will be called when i refresh the page. So it is working. But is there any option to call a function in different media screen size

Comment: can not say what is the problem, because $(window).resize fires whenever you change the window size. So it should work for you when you resize the window.

Comment: I have declared the above code as global to that page. Whenever window is resized controller won't be called right. May be because of that the above code won't be called when window size is resized.  If i resize the window and refresh page then controller is called and at that time value is reset according to that window size. Can i use the above code inside @media screen

Comment: One more thing, you have used static value in many conditions in js as well as html like $scope.displayrole.length >= 5, you should avoid these hard coded 5 from your code and use variable $scope._lastRoleIndex in place of it. Also edited my code check once.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130924/discussion-between-manoj-lodhi-and-kalai).